# Facebook API /{ad-account-id}/assigned_users with message: The user ID provided is not business scoped. Please provide a business or a system user ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm working on Facebook Grapth API.
Following up on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/ad-accounts#adaccounts-add-people).
I use the correct ID but they response that `The user ID provided is not business scoped`

I know the user param is a business user id. Then I tried to get the user_id by this api:

[image]

To make sure it's a business user id, I did another request:

[image]

And then, this was the result when I tried the request to add user to the ads account

[image]

Comment: You don't have this submitted & approved in review yet, I'd assume, so the user probably needs a role in the app, for this to work - that the case?

Comment: The test user is already a developer account! My app is really being reviewed.